# Passing string from C# to C .dll - getting extra characters

Tags: c#, c, dll

I am working on a C# project that will use a .dll (written in C)  When passing a char array to the .dll function runInterpretation I am getting extra characters added to my string.

C# code:

```
[DllImport(@"c:\projectName\main.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "runInterpretation")]

public static extern int runInterpretation(char[] inputStr);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputString = "DR1234,2014/07/27 15:20:10,1,0,3,0,0,2,5,30,10,10,0,55,205,21500,86400,110,0,";

    int tmp = runInterpretation(inputString.ToCharArray());

}
```

Which calls a C .dll:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                      
#include <time.h>                                                                       
#include <string.h>                                                                     

#include "fixedtext.h"                                                              
#include "englarrini.h"
#include "numarrini.h"                                                              
#include "argcvalue.c"                                                              
#include "dgavalid.c"                                                                   
#include "ratio.c"                                                                      
#include "interp.c"                                                                     
#include "validdisplay.c"                                                           

#ifdef DEVX
#define DATAFILEPATH "/home/drmcc/log/"                             
#elif DEVY
#define DATAFILEPATH "/home/drmcc/log/"                             
#elif PC
#define DATAFILEPATH ".\\data\\"                                            
#else
#define DATAFILEPATH ".\\data\\"                                            
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) int runInterpretation(char *inputString[])
{
    printf("args %s\n", inputString);

    return 1;
}
```

The end result when running my C# project is as follows (random extra chars after the last ',')

[image]

I would like to know why the extra characters are being added and how might I get rid of them.

Thank you

Comment: I call shenanigans on your claimed output -- you're passing an array of 16-bit character data, and decoding it as 8-bit character data.  The high byte of the first character is NULL and will be seen by C as the end of the string.  Also, your C code expects a double pointer, but your p/invoke declaration passes only a pointer.  Therefore, this is not your real code.

Comment: I am at a loss for words here.  The only thing that is altered is the use of "projectName" in the C# DllImport line.

Comment: At a minimum, your C code is missing `#include <stdio.h>`  Maybe you also have some very weird macros that cause the C code not to behave as written?

Comment: Or you might be using a version of the DLL built from different code (changed the code, forgot to copy the resulting DLL to your C# project)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you want what you have for your C dll's argument.  If you're just wanting one string passed in, then it should be:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int runInterpretation(char *inputString)
```

or better:

__declspec(dllexport) int runInterpretation(wchar_t *inputString)

From there, you just need to tell C# how to marshal your string.  The easiest way to do that is to use the MarshalAsAttribute.  If you go with the char * interpretation, use

```
public static extern int runInterpretation(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
String inputStr);
```

or the Unicode version:

```
public static extern int runInterpretation(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
String inputStr);
```

It's also worth noting that if you change your C parameter to Unicode, you don't have to use the Marshalling hint at all in C# as it will marshal correctly by default.

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are expected to be null terminated. The "extra characters" are whatever happens to be in memory after the array until a null character is found. `ToCharArray()` won't append a null character because that wouldn't make sense in the context of C#. I can think of two ways to fix this:

- Assuming you can change the API of the C DLL, add a second length parameter, and use that to make sure you don't go past the end of the array
- Append a null character to the string prior to calling `ToCharArray()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794356/3857 for an example

Comment: Third way: fix the p/invoke declaration

Comment: adding a null character to the end of the string prior to calling ToCharArray() appears to have gotten rid of the "extra" characters.  Thank you.

Comment: Ben, I am curious as to what is wrong with the p/invoke declaration.  Maybe I missed it in your previous comments.

Comment: @RCZiegler I think he is meaning to use a string rather than a char array in the p/invoke declaration like in the answer by DrewB. That would work as well, and is probably a better solution since that lets the CLR marshal the string correctly.