# Sending String over TCP/IP uisng C#

Tags: c#, matlab, tcp

I have a robotic system that can be interacted with over TCP/IP. I have been able to control the system in Matlab using the following code:

```
AT = tcpip('cim-up',8000);
fopen(AT);
fprintf(AT, '$global[1] = 33');
```

I need to emulate the same command in C#. I have tried the following code:

```
// Connect to Robot using TCPIP

string IP = "cim-up";
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

try
{
    tcpclnt.Connect(IP, 8000);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed");                
}

StreamWriter AT_writer = new StreamWriter(tcpclnt.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

AT_writer.Write("$global[1]=33");
```

This code will connect to the TCP/IP address but the server does not respond to the $global[1]=33 command.

I have also tried the following:

```
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$global[1]=33");         

// Get a client stream for reading and writing.

NetworkStream stream = tcpclnt.GetStream();

// Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as I have a successful Matlab implementation?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you have to flush the stream?

Comment: This code will connect to the TCP/IP address but the server does not respond to the $global[1]=33 command. - just added this to the main article as (thanks to you) i realised i hadn't mentioned my issue

Comment: i have just added `AT_writer.Flush();` after `AT_writer.Write("$global[1]=33");` but this did not help

Comment: Isn't matlab sending "C-like" strings ? (null-terminated). Maybe you could take inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793548/how-to-get-a-null-terminated-string-from-a-c-sharp-string

Comment: (basically, try to add `char.MinValue` at the end of your string, and then send `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yourString)`

Comment: so after packet sniffing matlab adds 0a to the string which is a line feed. Therefore the solution is `AT_writer.Write("$global[1]=33\n");
                AT_writer.Flush();`

Comment: In c# a \n is 0x0c, 0x0a (windows).  In matlab is is \r\n.  That maybe why you are using the Flush().

Comment: @ChristopherWright nice reverse engineering with packet sniffing. You should then write this as an answer to your own question.