# How do I get bytes including a null termination char from a string?

Tags: c#, string, null, byte, termination

Hello StackOverflowers,

I read somewhere that C# string are not null terminated. M'fine ! But I'd like to know if the method :

```
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString);
```

add a null termination character to the end of the array or if I must do it manually ? (the C system which will use this array does need it).

If manual, I guess the way would be :

```
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString + '\0');
```

The data is meant to be ASCII, no worries about encoding.

Comment: If your question essentially boils down to "how do I correctly marshal a string to unmanaged code expecting a null-terminated string?" then there are completely different options and answers available to you.

Comment: Are you passing this to an unmanaged function via P/Invoke? Because if so, the chances are that you're doing this wrong... The NUL character will be added automatically if you declare your P/Invoke correctly.

Answer (score 3):

---

> add a null termination character to the end of the array or if I must do it manually

**TL;DR** - it depends.  You don't need it for pure .NET development.  **If you intend to use p-invoke to native code, well .NET does the translation** for you, so again you don't.

---

> I read somewhere that C# string are not null terminated

Correct.

MSDN:

> A string is an object of type String whose value is text. Internally, the text is stored as a **sequential read-only collection of Char objects. There is no null-terminating character at the end of a C# string**; therefore a C# string can contain any number of embedded null characters ('\0'). The `Length` property of a string represents the number of Char objects it contains, not the number of Unicode character. -  [Tell me more...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)

OP:

> But I'd like to know if the method `byte[] myBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString);`
>   add a null termination character to the end of the array or if I must do it manually

No it doesn't and you don't need to, unless of course you wish to pass a string to **native code** via **p-invoke** but that is a completely different question (and is handled for you anyway by .NET).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't add, your second code will work.

```
byte[] myBytes = 
         Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("A"); // gives {65}

byte[] myBytes = 
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("A"+"\0"); // gives {65, 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetBytes` does not add a null termination character. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794356/4416750), you can just add `char.MinValue` to the end of your string.

```
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString + char.MinValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/using-null-terminated-strings)

> Your Unicode applications should always cast zero to TCHAR when using
>   null-terminated strings.

So, to have a null-terminated string, we have to add a byte in the end by this code. The default value of `byte` is `0`

```
byte[] bytes= Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
byte[] bytesNull = new byte[bytes.Length + 1];
bytes.CopyTo(bytesNull , 0);
```