# How many bytes does a null-terminator take based on a chosen encoding?

Tags: c#, string

`Encoding.GetByteCount(String)` tells me how many bytes it will take to represent a given C# `string` in a `byte[]` based on a chosen encoding but an external protocol demands strings are null-terminated *and* that the total size of the message containing the string is sent in a header.

Is calculating the size of my `char[]` as simple as adding 1 `byte` to the result of `GetByteCount(String)`, or might my NULL-terminator be different size based on encoding too? If so how can I determine this?

I am asking in the general case, not about a specific encoding.

e.g. `int HowManyNullBytesToAdd(Encoding encoding)`

Comment: I guess you could try GetByteCount(yourString + "\0");

Comment: I assume the size sent is bytes and not characters.  Character are a combination of 1 and two byte characters.  So you do not care if a byte array is terminated.   All you care about is the X number of bytes that are sent before the data.

Comment: Based on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) "in Modified UTF-8 the null character is encoded as two bytes: 0xC0, 0x80"

Comment: what is the encoding being used in the sent data -- that is what matters.

Comment: @jdweng _"an external protocol demands strings are null-terminated"_

Comment: @Hogan it might change, this is the point of the question

Comment: then how you count the null will change.

Comment: @Hogan then please provide an answer describing how

Comment: See also [How do I get bytes including a null termination char from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51382103/402022)

Comment: @Theraot why do you link to a question marked as a dupe? It seems they suggest `+\0'` in a non-accepted answer but it'd be nice not to have to create a new string to get the answer

Comment: Terminating strings and sending/receiving bytes are two different network layers.  Do not try to combine the layers.  You application will terminate the strings. The transmit layers will check the message that the correct number of bytes were received.

Comment: I can't describe how -- I have to know what encoding you are sending in... if you don't know what the format is then you have write code that does not know.

Comment: You say that an "external protocol" has a particular requirement, and then you ask us what that requirement is. We don't know; we didn't write the code that is accepting the buffer you're passing! The author of that code knows what they are expecting; that's the person you should ask.

Comment: But it seems plausible that the right thing to do is to just null-terminate the string *before* you encode it, and then pass the encoded string; is there some reason why you're resisting that solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all commonly used encodings, the simple answer to your question is

```
MyEncoding.GetByteCount("\0")
```

However, if you want to consider full generality then you might consider arbitrary encodings, perhaps not even part of any standard, encodings that you or I can invent. And then all bets are off. In that full generality, then I think you'd need to know more about the specific encoding.

However, for the most commonly used Unicode encodings, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32, the simple code above is vaiid.

Comment: Simple is good. Thanks for confirming this is solution is sound.

Comment: Is it the case for all string encodings that count of bytes is linear? That is, `bytecount(x) + bytecount(y) == bytecount(x + y)` ? That is not true for many string encodings such as run-length encoding; do you know for a fact that it is true of all Unicode encodings?  (This is not a rhetorical question; I genuinely do not know the answer and am curious as to whether you do.)

Comment: @Eric UTF8 and UTF16 are linear maps, considered as mapping from UTF32. It follows obviously that the byte lengths are also linear. Now I guess you could invent a Unicode encoding that wasn't linear, but I think that 8, 16 and 32 are all that exist today, no?

Comment: Regarding, what Unicode encodings exist today: you omit UTF-7, which is seldom used. A quick look at Wikipedia reveals that UTF-1 is essentially unused, UTF-5 and -6 were proposed but never adopted as formal standards, and UTF-9 and -18 were April Fools Day jokes.

Comment: That said, my concern arises because the question asks for the *general solution, rather than a solution for any particular encoding*. If in fact there is in practice no "general solution" because in general we only ever use one of three specific encodings, then that is certainly worth calling out.

Comment: @Eric I'd never looked at UTF-7 until now. Pretty wild west. It even allows encoders to encode the same text in different ways. As far as the null terminator goes, I have no idea if that's even a thing for UTF-7. I do take your point though that `Encoding` is so general that my blanket statement is not sustainable at least in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Byte count to represent your string in bytes depends on the encoding the receiver expects. so following may give not the same results if your string contains non-ascii characters.

```
var byteCountASCII = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(yourCharArray);
var byteCountUTF8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(yourCharArray);
```

If it is ASCII you can safely add 1 to it for null character but as far as i know for example UTF16 uses 2 bytes even for simple ascii characters so that depends also.

Comment: Yes that is what my question asks... how do I determine how many extra bytes to add for the NULL based on the encoding?

Comment: if that service written in c# or java and strings are unicode possibly it uses 2bytes for every char including null char. you have to know what encoding to use anyway.